# Change the comment upvote "Up Arrow" to a "Thumbs Up" in the Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, user-interface, comment-voting

This is just a minor suggestion, but I think the "up arrow" button that appears in the action bar when selecting a comment on the Android app should be changed to "thumbs up".

After all, the button is used to give 'score' to a good (or amusing) comment. (Or, using the terminology of a certain social media, to "like" the comment.)

Yes, the website uses an up arrow to do this. But I don't think it is necessary to fully emulate this piece of interface in the context of a mobile app.

Comment: Heh heh . After all, the side effect is different from the upvote button on a Q or an A: upvotes on a Q/A moves the Q/A higher. Upvoting a Comment makes it not hidden when there are a lot of Comments. By making the symbol different, it kind of hints at the different effect of Upvoting vs 'Liking'.

Comment: We aren't a social media site. Why should we try to emulate one?

Comment: This might fit in some third party app, but not in the official SE app. Its whole point is to emulate the actual SE sites.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

👎

Upvoting a comment *shouldn't* be a sign of simply liking it. I'll let the comment upvote tooltip from the website explain:

[image: this comment adds something useful to the post.]

While in practice comments are often upvoted simply because they are "liked," we shouldn't be making the association between upvoting and the intended meaning that the comment is *useful* any weaker. Changing the up-arrow to a thumbs-up on any of the platforms would, in my opinion, make upvoting comments seem much more casual, thereby taking away from the intended signal.